# table_open_cache won't increase above 431 - MariaDB 5.5

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Moved a few sites to a new server running CentOS 7, Plesk Onyx, 32gb, 2x480gb SSD, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1521 @ 2.40GHz.

```
[root@server ~]# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Trying to tune MySQL, but am stuck on the table_open_cache not going above 431.

```
| Open_tables                              | 431         |
```

My /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf as follows:

```
skip-name-resolve               = 1

innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 16G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 16
innodb_log_file_size            = 2G

tmp_table_size                  = 256M
max_heap_table_size             = 256M

thread_cache_size               = 4
table_open_cache                = 2000

query_cache_type                = 0
query_cache_size                = 12M
```

Already checked the OS limit:

```
[root@server /]# ulimit -n
4096
```

Not sure where to look next.  Any ideas or help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `Open_tables` being 431, I assume that you have only 431 tables in all the databases?  Or at least only that many are in use?

What is the value of `table_open_cache`?

What is the value of `Table_open_cache_misses / Uptime`?  If that is less than, say, 1/sec, then the `table_open_cache` is "big enough".

Comment: There are 660 tables on the server.  As for how many are in use I would guess 90% of those.  The value of table_open_cache is 2000.  I am not seeing a 'table_open_cache_misses" value in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  Would it be somewhere else?

Comment: Oops; that did not show up until 5.6.6.  Check out `Opened_tables / Uptime`.  Under 2/second is reasonable.  Since the structure is a _cache_, it is not necessary to have room for all tables.

Comment: opened_tables (~15k) / uptime (~90k) is roughly 0.17.  I'll continue to watch this, however it appears opened_tables is no longer climbing. While this makes me feel better about the setting being okay, it doesn't help with figuring out why the setting isn't going above 431, which I'd like to figure out.

Comment: In the first hour after starting mysql, Opened_tables/Uptime will be rather high -- because you are running queries, which need tables, which go into the table_cache.  It is wise to ignore `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` until the system has been running a day.

Comment: I have failed to explain '431', but I hope I have convinced you that it is not a problem.

Comment: You have, and I appreciate that.  I still would like to understand why this is happening though.

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;`?

Comment: Hey Rick - last comment was over two years ago.  Thanks for following up though!  And sorry it took me as long to mark the answer!

Comment: @LukePittman - 2 years led me to come up with another idea.

Comment: Haha - awesome man.  lol